# jQuery - select groups of child elements based on the parent DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, lightbox

I have a normal html page with stuff like divs and links with images:

```
<div>
  <a href="foo.jpg"> ... </a>
  <a href="boo.jpg"> ... </a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="bah.jpg"> ... </a>
  <a href="gah.jpg"> ... </a>
</div>

...
```

I'm trying to hook a lightbox script on all links that end with jpg/gif/png extensions.

Right now, based on a previous question I asked :), I have:

```
 $('div a').filter(function(){
   return this.href.match('[\.jpg|\.png|\.gif]$');
 }).colorbox({
   rel: 'gallery'
 });
```

which groups all links inside `gallery`.

But I would want to group links from each div inside their own gallery. For example .foo' & .boo links inside a `gallery1` and .bah & .gah inside `gallery2` and so on...

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('div').each(function(index) {
   $(this).find('a').filter(function(){
       return this.href.match('[\.jpg|\.png|\.gif]$');
   }).colorbox({
       rel: 'gallery' + index
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

(sorry, can't comment on the other answer)

Your regex needs parentheses, not brackets:

`(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$`

otherwise you're literally matching the characters `.jpgpnif|` and a filename of `foo|` matches.